# FunctionConstructor.prototype - Prototype

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, prototype

Если

```js
let variable = new FunctionConstructor();
```

то `variable.__proto__` = `FunctionConstructor.prototype`.

Что такое `variable.__proto__` (объект, от которого наследуется `variable`) понятно, а чему равно свойство `prototype` функции-конструктора нет.

1. "Какое смысловое значение (желательно имеющее отношение к объектам реального мира) имеет `FunctionConstructor.prototype`?"

P.S. Такой же вопрос возник относительно кода с [F.prototype](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-prototype), а именно как логически взаимосвязано свойство `Rabbit.prototype` со своим значением (какой смысл несет `Rabbit.prototype`)?

2. Если `let variable = new FunctionConstructor();`, то с одной стороны `variable` наследуется от `FunctionConstructor` (т. к. создана с помощью оператора `new FunctionConstructor();`), а с другой стороны `variable.__proto__=FunctionConstructor.prototype` (опять же потому что создана с помощью оператора `new`), т. е. `variable` прототипно наследуется от `FunctionConstructor.prototype`. В чем отличие прототипного наследования от обычного?
3. Объясните логику равенства с [Прототипы](https://habr.com/ru/post/140810/)

> Все типы данных наследуются от Object, это означает что к примеру:
> `Number.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`

Исходя из определения прототипа получаем, что переменная типа `Number.prototype = new Object()`.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос, отмените закрытие вопроса, т. к. вопрос нужный, особенно для новичка.

Comment: Добавь расшифровку, что ты понимаешь под _семантическим значением в аспекте свойств сущностей реального мира_

Answer (score 3):

- Конструктор - это вид: кот, енот, собака.
- его prototype - хранилище умений этого вида: мяукать, вылизываться.
- Родительский класс - более общая сущность в иерархии: млекопитающее, животное.
- его prototype - хранилище более общих умений: есть, ходить, издавать звук.

Comment: Вы забыли указать про параметры состояния. ;-)

Comment: @DiD, какие и где?

Comment: @Qwerty, прототип может хранить параметры и прочие дескрипторы. Хотя, непосредственно параметры состояния скорее относятся к объекту, а не прототипу.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно пояснить с помощью переменных? И что скажите по пункту2?

Comment: @Qwertiy внесите ясность на примере переменных.

Comment: @ProgrammerOfParadoxThings, что-то ты весь вопрос переписал :(